# Ассемблерные вставки c++

Tags: c++

Где можно найти перечень команд, которые можно использовать в `asm`-вставках?

Comment: Там можно использовать инструкции, которые поддерживает Ваш процессор. Следовательно, нужна спецификация инструкций Вашего процессора. Причём какие-то компиляторы могут накладывать свои ограничения на этот набор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это нестандартное расширение, зависящее от компилятора и платформы. Так что надежнее всего - в документации к компилятору.